# Powershell - Clustered DIsk Info - Duplicates

Tags: sql-server, windows-clustering

I have the following little code which collects disk space info from standalone and clustered environments (MS SQL Servers):

```
Get-WMIObject -query "select * from Win32_Volume where DriveType=3 and not name like '%?%'" -computername $svr |select @{n="ServerName";e={$svr}},
Name, Label, FileSystem, @{e={($_.BlockSize /1KB) -as [int]};n="DskClusterSizeInKB"},  @{e={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.Capacity / 1GB)};n="DskTotalSizeInGB"},  
@{e={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.Freespace /1GB)};n="DskFreeSpaceInGB"}, @{e={"{0:N2}" -f (($_.Capacity-$_.Freespace) /1GB)};n="DskUsedSpaceInGB"}, 
@{e={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.Freespace/$_.Capacity*100)};n="DskPctFreeSpace"}, @{n="DateAdded";e={$RunDt}}
```

If the $srv is a clustered network name then we have multiple times the same info collected for the disks

i.e Let’s say i have two instances [Inst1\InstName, Inst2\InstName] (clustered) with drive letters and mountpoints and those instances are on the same physical node.

When the collection starts (looping though the list of servers) it will go through the $srv=Inst1 collect the info, which will include the disks for Inst2.

Then when $srv=Inst2 it will include the disks for Inst1

Any ideas how to work around this?

Regards,
demisco

Comment: DeviceID is part of the payload from the WMI query. It appears to be a GUID, so you shouldn't have any disks that have the same ID that aren't in fact the same disk. TL;DR - use it to dedupe your data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: DeviceId is a good idea but i believe will not serve me much.
When the loop collects data for $srv=Inst1, it will pull all the disks of all the instances found on the specific server. 
This is where i have "extra data" for the specific $srv value.